# hypens not woking in URL wordrpess

Tags: wordpress, blogs

Below are my URL's

This URL gives 404 error because there is a hyphen(-) in URL

https://www.domainlist.com/blog/filter/technology-blog/

Same URL structure works as there are no hyphens

https://www.domainlist.com/blog/filter/security/

If I change the slug of the first URL and remove hyphens from it then the page will work.

I want to keep hyphen in URL

Does anyone have idea about this issue?